# php reference variables from another file

Tags: php, mysql, database, input

I'm trying to figure out how to access the data saved to a variable from another file.

So for instance, `firstfile.php` will contain the code:

```
$dbusername = $_POST["username"];
```

The inputted data (username in this case) is then used to create a table in my database which should be saved to the variable `$dbusername`.

and then `secondfile.php` will contain the code:

```
include "firstfile.php";
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$mysql_qry = "INSERT INTO `".$dbusername."` VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email')";
```

However, the variable `$dbusername` is appearing blank in the `secondfile.php`, i.e. no text, which then creates an error as the username, password and email cannot be saved to a non-existent table and I'm not quite sure as to why `$dbusername` is appearing blank.

I've tried to set the variable as:

```
$dbusername = "hi";
```

Which works perfectly fine when referenced into the second file, however, it just appears blank if I try to do it my intended way.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you want to do that? You need to rethink this.

Comment: Ideally? Yes. It's the last step to finish off my project, and I don't really want to scrap everything. So I was hoping I could figure out this inconvenience.

Comment: Well there isn't much else that I can do, not without knowing which api you used to connect and query with and what the HTML/form looks like. I can't suggest error checking links for mysql since I don't know which api is used. Someone gave an answer under comments, see that.

Comment: You will either have to pass that data along from “file” 1 to file 2 the same way it was passed to file 1 in the first place (i.e., use GET or POST), or you will have to store it into a _session_ inside of file 1, so that it can be accessed from there in file 2.

Answer (score -1):

this is happening because PHP is running inside one request and when you are including this file PHP will try to set "$dbusername" with the value of "$_POST["username"]" in this moment. But in this request there is no key in the post variables for "username". You may define a file like this:

```
<?php return ['username' => 'USERNAME'];
```

and then access the username like this:

```
$username = require('username_files.php');
```

But in this instance you describing i think scalability is absolutly not working and you should think about [sessions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php).